# jQuery get the selected dropdown value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a dropdown on change (and then change the values in a second dropdown).

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the replies, i've updated to add the () but the code is returning nothing, not null or undefined just a blank alert window

However when I alert it out the attr(value) is undefined.

Any ideas on what i'm missing?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var roomID = "0"
                $('.dropone').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx');
                $('.droptwo').load('ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=room&roomid=' + roomID);

                $('.dropone').change(function() {
                var ts = new Date().getTime();
                alert($(this).val)

                    $(".droptwo").empty();
                    $(".droptwo").load("ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=room&roomid=" + $(this).attr("value") + "&ts=" + ts);
                });

            });        
        </script>
```

Comment: .dropone is a select element ?

Comment: you forgot the `()` in `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a method, not a property.

use it like    `val()`

If you are using it many places, i would assign it to a local variable and use it thereafter.

Also you can use the [`$.now()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) function to get the unique time stamp. It is equal to DategetTime();

```
$('.dropone').change(function() {    
    var item=$(this);
    alert(item.val())
    $(".droptwo").empty();
    $(".droptwo").load("ajaxdropdown.aspx?drpType=room
                        &roomid=" +item.attr("value") + "&ts=" + $.now());
});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$('.dropone').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val(); 

  // OR

  var val = this.value;
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You must obtain the value using a method, not a property. Use this:

```
alert($(this).val())
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it now returns nothing, not undefined however nothing is returned

Comment: @TomBeech - That sounds like an HTML problem. Can you show the HTML for your dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Add round brackets to your val: `alert($(this).val())`

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain custom attributes from the dropdown as below;

```
     $('.someclass').change (function () { 
              var val = this.value;
              alert(val);                                       //selected value

               var element = $(this).find('option:selected');  // assign selected element
               var myTag = element.attr("aTag");              // get attribute by name
               alert(myTag);
    });


<option name='somename' id='someid' aTag='123' value='XYZ'>XYZ</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check **jQuery** and **Javascript** methods [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-jquery-javascript/) to get Single/ Multiple selected values in the Drop Down

**Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/getDropDownValue_JavaScript_jQuery.html)**

jQuery Method:
Method to get Selected Value from a select box:

**HTML**

```
<select id="singleSelectValueDDjQuery" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Select Value 0</option>
    <option value="8">Option value 8</option>
    <option value="5">Option value 5</option>
    <option value="4">Option value 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="textFieldValueJQ" class="form-control"
    placeholder="get value on option select">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#singleSelectValueDDjQuery").on("change",function(){
    //Getting Value
    var selValue = $("#singleSelectValueDDjQuery").val();
    //Setting Value
    $("#textFieldValueJQ").val(selValue);
});
```

Method to get **Selected Value Option Text** from a select box:

**HTML**

Select Value 0
        Option value 8
        Option value 5
        Option value 4

```
<input type="text" id="textFieldTextJQ" class="form-control"
                placeholder="get value on option select">
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#singleSelectTextDDjQuery").on("change",function(){
    //Getting Value
    var selValue = $("#singleSelectTextDDjQuery :selected").text();
    //Setting Value
    $("#textFieldTextJQ").val(selValue);
});
```