# How to Select an item from Dropdown Menu using while Loop in Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

How do I select a particular item from the following drop-down code using while loop in php ?

I am able to populate the drop-down,but unable to select a particular item from the drop-down. Please Help, if you can. Thanks.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="submit" for="no_id">
    <?php 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM crap";
        $select_dropdown = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        #function confirm stores in functions.php
        confirm($select_dropdown);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_dropdown)){
            $keyas_id= $row['keyas_id'];
            $valueas_title =$row['valueas_title'];
            echo "<option value=$keyas_id>  $valueas_title </option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: use [`jQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991007/jquery-get-the-selected-dropdown-value-on-change)

Comment: What do you mean by `select`? Do you want one of the options to be show as selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$selectedId = 'Your selected ID';
$isSelected = '';

if ( $keyas_id === $selectedId) {
    $isSelected = "selected='selected'";
}
echo "<option value=$keyas_id $isSelected>  $valueas_title </option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add if condition within option to compare whether `keyas_id` is equal to `selected_id` and if it is equal then you can select that like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select name="submit" for="no_id">
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM crap";
    $select_dropdown = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    #function confirm stores in functions.php
    confirm($select_dropdown);
    $selectedId = 'Your selected ID';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_dropdown)){
        $keyas_id= $row['keyas_id'];
        $valueas_title =$row['valueas_title'];
        echo "<option if($keyas_id==$selectedId) { selected='selected' } value=$keyas_id>  $valueas_title </option>";
    }
?>
</select>
</div>
```